# InputStream Non Blocking read operation

Tags: java, android

I have the scenario where i need to confirm that either the server side socket closed the connection or not.So for this i am checking if(in.read() ==-1) if true ,it means that server side closed the connection.
But problem is that if it does not it blocks here as it is blocking call.i need such a solution where i can read non blocking in perticular time or cancel the reading if server end closed the connection.
i am creating like

```
socket = new Socket();
                 // if server is not available 3 seconds blocking call other wise Exception
                 socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(serverAddress , serverPort),3000);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,
Aamir

Comment: Please post your code as it's almost impossible to work out what you're trying to do without knowing how you're opening to connection to the server. i.e. are you using `HttpClient`, `URLConnection`, raw sockets, etc.?

Answer (score 2):

> But problem is that if it does not it
>   blocks here as it is blocking call.

That's not the only problem. There is a miuch bigger problem: it will throw away a byte of data if any data ever arrives. You certainly cannot do that.

What you need is a timed read. See `Socket.setSoTimeout()`.

Comment: I can't upvote this answer enough. `setSoTimeout()` is very very well hidden :/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is for TCP, have you tried using `myClientSocket.isClosed()`?

Comment: It always returning me false.

Comment: This is not a solution. It doesn't tell you whether the peer closed the connection. It tells you whether *you* closed the connection.

Comment: yes EJP is right.i dont have control on server.so i cannot forcefully close the server.